# fullpage.js parallax and fade breaking resizing of page

Tags: fullpage.js

Taken some time but finally found the issue with fullpage.js not resizing the window correctly.

If you scroll to the second section and resize the window you will see the fullpage.js finds the middle where 2 slides join.

this only happens when fade and parallax extension is being used together.
if i disable "false" fade then this issue stops.

So you need to scroll to section 4, then change the size of the window. can anyone replicate this problem?

```
        anchors: ['home', 'investment-platform', 'golden-visa', 'ahimsa-investments'],
        controlArrows: true,
        menu: '#menu',
        animateAnchor: false,
        slidesNavigation: false,
        navigation: false,
        fadingEffect: 'slides',
        parallax: 'sections',
        parallaxOptions: {
            type: 'reveal',
            percentage: 50,
            property: 'translate',
        },
        css3:true,
        easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000)',
        scrollingSpeed: 600,
        autoScrolling: true,
        scrollBar: hasScrollBar,
        bigSectionsDestination: null,
        fitToSection: true,
        fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
        lazyLoading: false,
        scrollOverflow: true, 
        verticalCentered: true,
```

Comment: I guess you use parallax vertically and fading horizontally or something around those lines? Because of course using them both for the same direction doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: i used parallax for sections and fade for slides.

Comment: Please [contact me](https://alvarotrigo.com/#contact) with an isolated reproduction.